# A department can belongsToMany, but a user can only belongTo department? How to pivot this correctly?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So im trying to figure out how to use pivot tables in Laravel. And I have tried to read and understand the documentation. And I cannot understand why a user just can't balongTo a "department". I don't want a user to belongToMany "departments".

Departments model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'department_user', 'user_id', 'department_id');
}
```

And for the user model, I want something like

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}
```

But Laravel reports `null`. Because `department_id` doesn't exist in the users row? How can I reverse this pivot table lookup, with `belongsToMany` and `belongsTo`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting confused with your relationship types. If I understand you correctly:

- A `Department` `hasMany` `User`s.
- A `User` `belongsTo` a `Department`.

This one-to-many relationship type does not need a pivot table and can be written as such:

```
class Department extend Eloquent
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}

class User extend Eloquent
{
    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
    }
}
```

This would require that the `users` table have a `department_id` foreign key.